# What are the differences between IE and, ehm, IE?

Tags: windows-8.1, desktop, internet-explorer-11, start-screen

I notice that there are very big differences between starting up IE from the desktop taskbar and starting it up from the Windows 8.1 start screen. Doing so results in a remarkably dissimilar user experience.

For instance, the IE started up from the start screen has fewer options (no menu bar, no F12 etc). It behaves like a totally different program. Also, the icons shown in the Alt+Tab display are different.

[image: screen shot of Alt+Tab display]

In fact, when I first noticed this, I thought maybe Microsoft had perhaps installed Edge on my machine. But no, both versions identify themselves as Internet Explorer 11.

So, why this difference? Why does the same program behave in such different ways depending on how it is started up? Am I missing something?

Comment: Where exactly is this screenshot from? I ask because the icons for the modern version of IE 11 and the desktop version of IE11 are very similar.  So I suspect that is the reason due the the poo quality of the screenshot, its not possible to actually tell what is going on within the actual browser though.

Comment: This particular screenshot is actually from a virtual machine witjh a trial version of W8.1 with IE11 (from Microsoft itself), but it's the same on a real Windows 8.1 computer.

Comment: You could have determined what the difference was from Task Manager by the way.

Comment: @Ramhound Are you sure? On my VB it only says "Internet Explorer" twice.

Comment: To the downvoter: it's not like I haven't done any research. Yes, it's easy to find with Google, if you know what you're looking for! Or is there something else wrong with my post? Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are 2 different types of IE on Windows 8/8.1

One is the "Modern IE" with some features removed and optimized for full screen experiences. The other is the desktop edition which has all the features and is optimized for Keyboard\Mouse usage

You can read about this in more detail at the MSDN page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh771832(v=vs.85).aspx